# How to model a network analysis problem

Tags: probability, bayesian, naive-bayes, social-network

I have a weighted graph in which the nodes represent users and weighted undirected edges represent the tie between a pairs of users. For a piece of content $c$, and a node $A$ in the graph, given that $A$ has viewed the content and a few of $A$'s neighbors have viewed it as well, the problem is to infer whether $A$ liked the piece of content or not. I am currently thinking of using a Naive Bayes approach.

Let's say $P(A_c = 1 | U_{1_c} =1 , U_{2_c} = 1,U_{3_c} = 0, U_{4_c} = 1,...,U_{nc})$ where $A_c = 1$ indicates that $A$ likes content $c$ and $U_{1_c}$ to $U_{n_c}$ indicate whether all of $A$'s neighbors liked the content $c$. In the above expression we are assuming that $U_{1_c}$ ..... $U_{n_c}$ are independent and have no effect on each other but the fact is that at some previous moment in time user $U_3$ might have adopted the content because he saw user $U_2$ and $U_4$ (who let us assume are also neighbors of $U_3$) adopt the content.

My question is whether this assumption will affect the accuracy of the model? And if so could you suggest a better model for this problem.

I have barely any statistics background so please forgive me for any blatant fallacies in the above equations or model.